# Always in a task?

Tags: verilog

I'm using Verilog for programming a FPGA.

I have my top module and I would like to call a `Task` which contains an `always` block.

The `Task` is a routine for serializing a byte in UART. (inputs: baudrate_clk, bytetosend ; output: TxD which is the physical output pin)

```
module serial();

task serial;
    input baudrate;
    input [7:0] data;
    output TxD;

    reg [3:0] state;

    begin
    always @(posedge baudrate) begin
        case(state)
            // ...
        endcase
    end
    end

    always @(state[2:0]) begin
            case(state[2:0])
            // ...
            endcase
    end
    assign TxD ...
    end
endtask
endmodule
```

I get a `unexpected token: 'always'` at the first `always`, `always @(posedge baudrate) begin`

I read Task could include wait, posedge etc...

If I cannot use Taks, what can I use for this purpose ?

Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, as far as I understood, you can use `always` block and call task repetitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your task should be a module or you should use a loop inside your task. It's difficult to see your design intent, but it looks to me that you needed a module in this case, not a task.
Tasks contain sequential code, just like an always block does. A task is just another place to put the kind of code that can go inside an always block. It makes no sense to put an always block inside a task.

Comment: Then you advice me to use a module with a "enable" bit in order to use it ? This is the first time I'm using an FPGA, and the sequential and combinational mix is hard to understand with blocking, nonblocking, reg and wire.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP It's rather hard to explain all that in one comment...Basically, everything between `module` and `endmodule` is concurent. So, if you have (eg) 2 `assign` statements and 3 `always` blocks in your module, you'll have 5 concurent threads. Code inside each `always` block is sequential. So is code inside a `task`. So, you can call  (strictly _enable_) a `task` from inside an `always` block. A `wire` is just that and can be driven from multiple places; a `reg` is a variable and, if driven from multiple places, the last assignment overwrites the previous one... _Verilog in a Nutshell_.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, I didn't understand very well the verilog/FPGA behavior. I read a lot and the behavior is more clear now. I read somewhere, 99% of projects can be done with only modules. By using wires at the end, enable and finish signals and then multiplexer, I should be able to do what I want. Thank you !